# Branch link donot proivide data when clicked and opened in android app

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I have created link using branch sample app and set everything as mentioned. [Branch sample app](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/tree/master/Branch-SDK-TestBed)
When a link is created i can see the data in  branch dashboard associated with that link. But whenever i click that link in my android device and app opens i get sessionparams and referparams both empty
I have tried

```
 Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
               String referringParamsString = (String) sessionParams.toString();
                      //{"+clicked_branch_link":false,"+is_first_session":false}
               JSONObject sessionParams = Branch.getInstance().getFirstReferringParams();
        //{Empty }

         }
     });
```

Please help, earlier it was working fine Now its not working . I have tried changing
Branch.getAutoInstance(this); ->Branch.getAutoInstance(this, true);
used JSONObject sessionParams = Branch.getInstance().getFirstReferringParams();  without Branch session.
Still i am not getting any values.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I work at [Branch](https://branch.io)

Session referring parameters will return the Branch link parameters for the current link which redirected the user to the app. The first session parameters, return the link parameters for the first link which brought the user to the app.

In the case of your app, it looks like a key mismatch issue i.e. your app could be using the test key while you are using the links created in the live version of the app for testing. If the Branch key used by your app is not the same as the Branch key for the link, the Branch SDK will not be able to fetch the link parameters and will return `+clicked_branch_link:false` for session parameters and will return `null` for the first referred session parameters.

To check if your app is using the test key, you can create a link in the test version of your app on the Branch dashboard and click on the link. If you get +clicked_branch_link:true it means your app is using the test key. (The links in the test version are of the format: https://yourapp-test.app.link/sbjdsRS).

You can ensure your app is using the live key instead of the test key by:

1. Completely removing the test key from your Android Manifest OR
2. Making sure you are not enabling Test Mode in your Android Manifest or your Application.

Comment: Hi @Amruta , thanks for responding. I have checked it from my side . Short url is generating successfully having all data sent( i can verify it from my dashboard.e.g https://myapp.app.link/).  I have removed all testing credentials. Still it is not passing data in the session.

Comment: I have tried with sample app too, its not giving data everytime, only in first session once  just after installing from studio. Please help.

Comment: @SimpleCoder so are you getting the link parameters the first time when you click on the link and install the app?

Comment: Only while using getFirstReferringParamsSync(). But this also is giving value even without clicking the link.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, the first referring link parameters will return the link parameters of the first Branch link of your app that the user clicked and installed/opened the app. If you wish to get link parameters of the current link you should use the referringParams returned in the initSession(). Are you not getting any link parameters in the referring session params?

Comment: @ Amruta Deshmukh , Can you please tell me, in which activity lifecycle method the Branch session router is recommended to be written ?